# E0167 argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

Tags: c++11, serial-port

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
std::vector<std::string> serialCOM::list_serial_ports()
{
    std::vector<std::string> ports;
    // Enumerate all available COM ports
    for (int i = 1; i <= 256; i++) {
        std::string port = "COM" + std::to_string(i);
        HANDLE hComm = CreateFile(port.c_str(), GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

    }
    return ports;
    
}
```

Expecting No Error for this line // CreateFile(**port**.c_str()
E0167 argument of type "const char *" is incompatible with parameter of type "LPCWSTR"

Comment: Welcome to SO! Thanks for giving us a chance to help. Please consider adding additional formatting to your question with perhaps a bit more context. As it is the few words you have at the bottom have unformatted code that may be difficult to decipher easily, lowering your chances of more answers. You can enclose code like that with a single back tick at the beginning and end of it.  I tried to edit it myself but after additional formatting it seems your question has too much code and requires more context per SO's guide lines.

Answer (score 1):

You are using [`CreateFileW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilew) which expects a `const wchar_t*` (which is what `LPCWSTR` is a `typedef` for). `port.c_str()` returns a `const char*` and these pointers are not compatible.

Either use [`CreateFileA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-createfilea) instead (which expects a `const char*` / `LPCSTR`) or make `port` a `std::wstring` and continue to use `CreateFileW`:

```cpp
std::wstring port = L"COM" + std::to_wstring(i);
HANDLE hComm = CreateFileW(port.c_str(), ...
```

Comment: Just to add a little more context to help clarify `LPCWSTR` is a long pointer to a wide string and/or a unicode string. Unicode is primarily for extending the basic character set by providing symbols from non-English languages like Chinese, Japanese, etc. `LPCSTR` is for ASCII strings that use the English alphabet. For a variety of Windows API functions there's a unicode and ascii version and the difference is noted with a post-fix of `A` or `W`. `CreateFileA` being ascii and `CreateFileW` being unicode.

Comment: @EdwardSeverinsen _"`LPCWSTR` is a long pointer ..."_ - It's simply a pointer. The "near" and "far" pointers from back in the Windows 16 bit days are probably not worth mentioning other than for historical reasons to explain where the `L` in `LP` comes from :-) Today the `LPCWSTR` definition is simply `const wchar_t*`.  `A` is for `ANSI`, not `ASCII`. You can use those functions with not only the English alphabet but for anything you have an [ANSI code page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/code-page-identifiers) for. There are quite a few Chinese and Japanese code pages.

Comment: Ah yes, you are indeed correct. For a long time I thought the two were essentially synonymous but after Googling it appears ANSI extends ASCII more than enough to warrant a distinction. And yeah, I just remember for a long time wondering why pointers were prefixed with `LP` sometimes so thought I'd throw it in. Thanks for setting me straight.